# how can I split data in 3 or more parts with sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation, train-test-split

I want to split data into train,test and validation datasets which are stratification, but sklearn only provides cross_validation.train_test_split which only can divide into 2 pieces.
What should i do if i want do this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use a Stratified Train/Test split, you can use [StratifiedKFold in Sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html)

Suppose `X` is your features and `y` are your labels, based on the example [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html) :

```
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
cv_stf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=3)
for train_index, test_index in skf.split(X, y):
    print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
```

**Update** : To split data into say 3 different percentages use [numpy.split()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) can be done like this :

```
X_train, X_test, X_validate  = np.split(X, [int(.7*len(X)), int(.8*len(X))])
y_train, y_test, y_validate  = np.split(y, [int(.7*len(y)), int(.8*len(y))])
```

Comment: thanks for answer,but i want to split a dataset into three pieces like[70%,20%,10%],StratifiedKFold may not help.

Comment: @loseryao oh sorry, I thought you mean into 3 different folds, I will update that.

Comment: Might be smart to shuffle the data.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `train_test_split` more than once to achieve this. The second time, run it on the training output from the first call to `train_test_split`.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

def train_test_validate_stratified_split(features, targets, test_size=0.2, validate_size=0.1):
    # Get test sets
    features_train, features_test, targets_train, targets_test = train_test_split(
        features,
        targets,
        stratify=targets,
        test_size=test_size
    )
    # Run train_test_split again to get train and validate sets
    post_split_validate_size = validate_size / (1 - test_size)
    features_train, features_validate, targets_train, targets_validate = train_test_split(
        features_train,
        targets_train,
        stratify=targets_train,
        test_size=post_split_validate_size
    )
    return features_train, features_test, features_validate, targets_train, targets_test, targets_validate
```